# Select elements from a character vector with strsplit

Tags: r, vector, string-parsing, strsplit

I have a character vector which looks like this:

```
chars <- c("Classics football boots", "Classics football shoes","football shoes", "new footbal shoes")
```

In this `chars` object i want to select only elements `football shoes & football boots`. With maintaining the order because i need to replace the vector back into a `dataframe`.

If tried many things but i think this comes most close:

```
for (i in grep("Classics",chars)){
  temp <- as.character(strsplit(chars[i], " ")[[1]][c(2,3)])
  temp2 <- as.character(na.omit(temp))
  chars[i] <- temp2
}
```

How can i get the object like this:

`c("football boots", "football shoes","football shoes", "new footbal shoes")`

So i only want to touch the values containing classics (or whatever word of interest).

Update:

Since I see that the question is not clear I will try to elaborate a bit more:

The vector that I have contains 4000 plus values. So I want to select values from the vector based on some string (in this example "Classics"). Then if I find that word I want to be able to select only parts of that string that are needed. In this example I want to select the second and third element of that value. Hope its more clear now.

Comment: What are the rules? It's not clear

Comment: You only wanna remove the word "Classics", that's it?

Comment: @Sotos What i need is just to be able to select certain elements from each separate value no matter what rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea using `grepl` and `word` from `stringr`,

```
chars[grepl('Classics', chars)] <- stringr::word(chars[grepl('Classics', chars)], 2, 3)
chars
#[1] "football boots"    "football shoes"    "football shoes"    "new footbal shoes"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply this:

```
gsub("Classics\\s+", "", chars)
# [1] "football boots"    "football shoes"    "football shoes"    "new footbal shoes"
```